# Facebook SDK Android Login Button error

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

I am new to Android app development and trying to create a simple activity with a Facebook login button. However, when I deploy the app on my phone, I get the following error:

```
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.fblogin, PID: 24890
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:822)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-09 04:48:44.260 24890-25085/com.example.fblogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have written the following .xml and .java codes:

**JAVA:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     />
```

I have also added the  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml. Any help here on how to make the FB Login thing working is highly appreciated. Facebook documentation kind of feels very less explanatory.

Comment: you can compare your code with my repository   https://github.com/David-Hackro/ExamplesAndroid/tree/master/Facebook

Comment: @DavidHackro: Thanks David. I looked at your code however couldn't find any substantial difference in the way initialization has been done. Although, I have re-run the code many times and have a hunch that there is some issue with registering the callback.....this is breaking my head!

Comment: in https://developers.facebook.com you have your App?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add permissions to your login button (before registering it callback), like:

   loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
2. Inside your onActivityResult try to add

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

before the callbackManager.onActivityResult method

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, however it is still not working. :(